# $P\left(X_1 < X_2 < X_3\right) = P\left(X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3|X_1\ne X_2\ne X_3\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, notation, bayes-theorem

**I have 3 independent random variables, $X_i$, distributed on a continuous uniform distribution between 0 and 1.**

Does the following hold given the assumptions above?

$$
\tag{1}
P\left(X_1 < X_2 < X_3\right) = P\left(X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3\left|X_1\ne X_2\ne X_3\right.\right)
$$

I call $A \equiv (X_1 < X_2 < X_3)$ and $B \equiv (X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3)$ and $P(N) \equiv P(X_1\ne X_2 \ne X_3)$ to simplify as,
$$
\tag{2}
P(A) = P(B|N)
$$

The probability, of events not equalling each other, $P(N)$ is defined by,

$$
\tag{3}
P(N) =  1 - P(X_1 = X_2 \cap X_2 < X_3) \cup P(X_1 < X_2 \cap X_2 = X_3) \cup P(X_1 =X_2=X_3)
$$

I investigate the probability of $P(X = a)$ for the continuous uniform distribution, by taking the following limit
$$
P\left(X=a\right)
= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} P\left(a-\epsilon < X \le a\right)
= \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int^{a}_{a-\epsilon} dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon = 0
$$
Thus, for a continuous uniform distribution between 0 and 1, $P(X_i=X_j)=\delta_{ij}$, so we get, $P(N) = 1$ for (3). We can transform (1) as follows,

$$
\tag{4}
P(A) = \frac{P(B \cap N)}{P(N)}
$$

because events $X_i$ are independent,

$$
\tag{5}
P(A) = \frac{P(B)P(N)}{P(N)} = P(A)
$$

Thus, $P(A) = P(B)$

Comment: How do you have a descrete r.v. $X_i$ which is a continuous uniform in [0,1]?

Comment: good comment. I just meant that X_i are points and not functions

Comment: Oh... thus. are you saying that $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are three observations from a $U[0,1]$? (please, note that i'm using lowercase letter)

Comment: Not sure if that is the same, since you are using lower case letters, I just meant that $X_i$ are individual points assigned a value from a continuous distribution $f(x)$. Perhaps it is clearer since I made the edit? I mean this in the normal usage of $P(X_i=x)$ as the probability of an observation where $i$ just differentiates between observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three independent and uniformly distributed continuous random variables will almost certainly not be coequal.   That is, $\mathsf P(X_1\neq X_2, X_2\neq X_3)=1$

$$\therefore\mathsf P(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\mathsf P(X_1\leq X_2\leq X_3)$$

Comment: Can this be extended to using conditional probability as above above though?

Comment: Yes, but why are you bothering?  What are you trying to establish?

Comment: Ensuring my probability manipulations are precise and correct in the exact notation I use above. I was recently led to believe the above was incorrect. I dreamt the proof last night and wrote it up this morning. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane "I was recently led to believe the above was incorrect." If you are referring to the exchanges we had à propos [this incomplete answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1618142/revisions) of yours, this was not what I led you to believe.